Confusion as to how to handle Islamic texts carefully
I cut up islamic texts with the Name of Allah and his messengers and sahaba names.Now I have read that in Radd al-Muhtar ala al-Durr al-Mukhtar, 5/271, it is said we must erase these names before shredding or burning these texts.How do I erase them, as the only water available is from the sinkand wouldn't the ink going down the drain be disrespectful.Some of these I have not cut properly as well but I have not disposed of any yet.What to do?Id di the same with quranic verses and hadiths, do i need to bury the pieces or put them into a river with a weight or what? I am not able to do these things. Should i justs tore them? How much cut up do they have to be if that is even allowed? Does every letter have to be completely indecipherable, often when  i was doing this and looked at them, i rhough the letter could be an e or a etc.Note:Most of these are in english.
